# How do you iterate over a list with a list of integers?

Tags: ansible

I want a list of boolean values, corresponding to whether or not a file exists.

```yaml
- name: test
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.results.0.stat.exists }}"
```

returns

```
TASK [test] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": true
}
```

So I need a list of numbers ranging from zero to the number of files

```yaml
- name: set fact test
  set_fact:
    outcome: "{{ result.results }}"
    numOfElems: "{{ repoFiles|length }}"
    numList: []
    boolList: []

- name: obtain index  list
  set_fact:
    numList: "{{ numList + item|list }}"
  with_sequence: start=0 end={{ numOfElems }}
```

Then I want to loop through the list and get the true/false value

```yaml
- name: obtain boolean list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ outcome.{{ item }}.stat.exists }}"
  with_items: "{{ numList }}"

- name: obtain boolean list
  set_fact:
    boolList: "{{ outcome.{{ item }}.stat.exists }}"
  with_items: "{{ numList }}"
```

The error produced:

```
TASK [output exists] ******************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected name or number. String: {{ outcome.{{ item }}.stat.exists }}"}
```

Not sure why I can't put the number into the template string.

Per accepted answer I get:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists') | list": [
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        false,
        true,
        true,
        true
    ]
}
```

Iterating through this output gives me characters: `"r","e","s","u","l","t"` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) the attribute you are looking for:

```yaml
- debug:
    var: result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists')
```

---

Given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    files:
        - /tmp/a
        - /tmp/b
        - /tmp/do-not-exists

  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: "{{ item }}"
      register: result
      loop: "{{ files }}"

    - debug:
        var: result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists')
```

This yields:

```
TASK [stat] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/a)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/b)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/tmp/do-not-exists)

TASK [debug] **************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists'):
  - true
  - true
  - false
```

Comment: My output from your suggestion is: "result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists')": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f444016c640>"

Comment: You are on an old version of Ansible, so you have to add a `| list` to cast back the generator to a list: `var: result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists') | list`

Comment: Hi, still having complication with your solution. I edited the question

Comment: If you are assigning this to a, mind that you need to put it in a variable block: `some_var: "{{ result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists') | list }}"` same if you want to loop it right away: `loop: "{{ result.results | map(attribute='stat.exists') | list }}"`

Answer (score 0):

try these tasks:

```
- name: obtain boolean list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ outcome[item].stat.exists }}"
  with_items: "{{ numList }}"

- name: obtain boolean list
  set_fact:
    boolList: "{{ boolList | d([]) + [ outcome[item].stat.exists ] }}"
  with_items: "{{ numList }}"

- name: display boolList
  debug:
    msg: "{{ boolList }}"
```